# optimized way for Inserting data in tables using stored procedure in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the best way to pump data into different tables using stored procedure? Assume I have around 1 million rows each in 3 different tables say A,B,C. Now based on some criteria I have to club data from these 3 and push it into another table say D. What is the optimized way to do this?

I need to add some business logic before inserting the data.

Comment: Hint:  `insert . . . select`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Actually I need to add some business logic before making insert. I edited my ques.

Comment: `insert into d select case when some_buisenes_logic then end from a join b,c...` ?.. just because iterating million rows in a loop will be hundred  times more expensive then select